# How do I convert an integer value to a char, e.g. 97 should print as 'a'

Tags: f#

I have an array of integer values representing counts of characters.
I want to print the character value as a letter followed by the count

For instance the 0 array member as a count for the letter 'a' and so on.

Comment: Use ``char 97`` You can map the function over the array. If you show some code it will be easy to tell how.

Answer (score 5):

Technically, this question is underdefined. `let f _ = 'a'` would be a correct answer. We need to know the desired encoding. But I think it's safe to assume that you are talking about one of the following encodings, filled up with leading zero-bits:

- ASCII
- UTF-8
- UTF-16
- Some 8b extended ASCII variant

Or, if you have a common misconception about what exactly .NET chars are, you could mean UTF-32. But it is not possible to convert all characters a UTF-32 int can represent to a single char. The `char` type is actually defined as a UTF-16 code unit.

Anyway, all of these encode 'a' as 97 if we disregard the amount of space used.

Here are some tools:

- [`char`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualfsharpdocs/conceptual/operators.char%5B%5Et%5D-function-%5Bfsharp%5D) converts numeric inputs as UTF-16, which is the internal encoding used by chars in .NET.
- Look at the [System.Text namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text(v=vs.110).aspx) and [System.Text.Encoding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding(v=vs.110).aspx) for various decoding tools, including reading UTF-8.
- ASCII are included in Unicode code points and can therefore be converted by the above as well – if the input chars are consistently within ASCII, i.e. have all but the least significant 7 bits zeroed.
- For the dated, culture-dependent 8-bit encodings, look for the appropriate encoding tools, similarly to above. Though it's questionable to use them in this day and age.
- [System.Char.ConvertFromUtf32](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.char.convertfromutf32(v=vs.110).aspx) gets you a string with up to two chars from UTF-32.

Answer (score 2):

```
let str = "Hello World!"

// Convert to an int array and group by key.
let count_array = 
    str.ToCharArray() 
    |> Array.map int 
    |> Array.groupBy id // Groups them by ints
    // Since the ints are the same in this case, we convert the array length to counts.
    // We also convert k back to char.
    |> Array.map (fun (k,ar) -> char k, ar.Length) 

printfn "%A" count_array

// [|('H', 1); ('e', 1); ('l', 3); ('o', 2); (' ', 1); ('W', 1); ('r', 1); ('d', 1);
//  ('!', 1)|]
```

The answer by Vandroiy has some pertinent information, but here is a simple way of doing what you have asked.

The above code is inefficient as I am converting from string to a char array to an int array and back to char. While on a individual level converting from char to int is a no-op, each of those function calls iterates over the array and creates a new one leaving it to the GC to dispose of the old one. This creates memory churn.